# SAS 9.3 Sorting Data by rows

Tags: sorting, sas

I have an excel file that I imported into SAS that contains 3 variables and 3 observations.

All values are numbers.

`24`   `12`  `47`

 `99`   `30`  `14`

 `50`   `5`   `41`

Is there a way I can code so that each **row** is sorted in ascending order?

Result would be:

`12`   `24`  `47`

 `14`   `30`  `99`

 `5`   `41`   `50`

I need to do this for several excel files that contain huge number of variables and observations. 

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way is to use CALL SORTN which sorts across rows.

```
data have;
input a b c;
datalines;
24 12 47 
99 30 14 
50 5 41
;
run;

data have;
modify have;
call sortn(of _numeric_);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a FCMP sort routine.  FCMP functions and subroutines only allow temporary arrays to be passed to them for modification.  So you have to assign the values into a temporary array, sort, and then reassign to the permanent variables.

Modify the code below for your number of columns and column names.

```
options cmplib=work.cmp;

proc fcmp outlib=work.cmp.fns;
subroutine qsort(arr[*],lo,hi);
    outargs arr;
    i = lo;
    j = hi;
    do while (i < hi);
        pivot = arr[floor((lo+hi)/2)];
        do while (i<=j);
            do while (arr[i] < pivot);
                i = i + 1;
            end;
            do while (arr[j] > pivot);
                j = j - 1;
            end;
            if (i<=j) then do;
                t = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = t;
                i = i + 1;
                j = j - 1;
            end;
        end;
        if (lo < j) then
            call qsort(arr,lo,j);
        lo = i;
        j = hi;
    end;
endsub;
run;
quit;

data test;
input a b c;
datalines;
24 12 47 
99 30 14 
50 5 41
;
run;

%let ncol=3;
%let cols = a b c;
data sorted;
set test;
array vars[&ncol] &cols;
/*Only temporary arrays can be passed to FCMP functions*/
array tmp[&ncol] _temporary_;

/*Assign to tmp*/
do i=1 to &ncol;
    tmp[i] = vars[i];
end;
/*Sort*/
call qsort(tmp,1,&ncol);
/*Put back sorted values*/
do i=1 to &ncol;
    vars[i] = tmp[i];
end;
drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there's a package SAS/IML designed specifically for manipulations with matrices (where, I believe, this task would be trivial), it still can be done with SAS Base using a couple of PROCs wrapped into macro loop.

```
data raw;
input a b c;
datalines;
24 12 47
99 30 14
50 5 41
;
run;

proc transpose data=raw out=raw_t(drop=_:); run;

proc sql noprint;
  select name into :vars separated by ' '
  from sashelp.vcolumn
  where libname='WORK' and memname='RAW_T';
quit;

%macro sort_rows;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&vars));

    proc sort data=raw_t(keep=%scan(&vars,&i)) out=column;
       by %scan(&vars,&i);
    run;

    data sortedrows;                  
       %if &i>1 %then set  sortedrows;;
       set  column;
    run;
%end;
%mend sort_rows;
%sort_rows

proc transpose data=sortedrows out=sortedrows(drop=_:); run;
```

First, you transpose your original dataset.

Then you iterate through all columns (which were rows originally) one by one, sorting them and right-joining to each other.

And finally, transpose everything back.